# 'Invalid override. The type isn't a subtype' when implementing an interface

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement the MealsRepository interface into the MealsRepositoryImpl, but I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid override. The type of 'MealsRepositoryImpl.findAllForCanteenByDate' ('(int, DateTime) -> Future Map int, dynamic ') isn't a subtype of 'MealRepository.findAllForCanteenByDate' ('(int, DateTime) -> Future Map int, Meal ').

I can't see my mistake. I'm currently using Intellij using the Dart plugin.

I've already updated the Dart and Flutter plugin.

```
abstract class MealsRepository {
  Future<Map<int, Meal>> findAllForCanteenByDate(int canteenId, DateTime date);
}

class MealsRepositoryImpl extends MealsRepository {

  MensaApi api;

  MealsRepositoryImpl(this.api);

  @override
  Future<Map<int, Meal>> findAllForCanteenByDate(int canteenId, DateTime date) {
    return api.getMealsForCanteenByDate(canteenId, date).then((meals) {
      return meals;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK - turns out the error was actually that I forgot to import the Meal class. Kinda stupid, but the error message wasn't really expressiv about it.